# mapping diagram of website flow interaction

Tags: web-applications, workflow, uml

I am not sure what type of workflow diagram standard I should be using to convey the flow of how web application would work to a non-technical and technical person.

Because for myself, as a tech person, I want to be able to know how certain components interacts with lets say a database, when it comes to the point I have to revisit.

In words I would describe them as this

Main page

```
  -> sign up page
      ->sign up connects to database if successful go to thank you page.
      ->sign up connects to database if successful go back to sign up page.    
  -> contact us
  -> etc...
```

Comment: In line three you probably mean "unsuccessful", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To describe a user interfaces (a web site), I prefer [state machines](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html). Each state of the state machine matches a state of you user interface, and the system reacts to the user interaction by changing its state. In each state you state what happens when the system is in that state by adding actions to the state. The actions show how the interface interacts with the system.

Answer (score 0):

This type of diagram is usually specified in an **Information Architecture** methodology.  Surprisingly, there is no, that I'm aware, widely used standard suggested in IA.  Other names are User Experience Design (UXD), Interaction Design (IxD), and so forth.  Each company or development tool supports different kinds.

*Here is one example approach*:
"A visual vocabulary for describing information architecture and interaction design": http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/

I like vainolo's suggestion, however, years ago I tried that and the stakeholders got bogged down in the most elementary concepts, like *state*.

What a non-technical stakeholder would understand more readily is a *UML* **Activity Diagram** (which is just a simple mashup of a Petri Net and a flowchart).  With the addition of "swimlanes", activity diagrams can model multiple pages and processes.  Though an Activity Diagram sounds complex, it is pretty easy to follow (for simple linear scenarios).

*Example Activity diagram*:
"UML Activity Diagrams: Detailing User Interface Navigation": http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4697.html

Answer (score 0):

How about the following for a start?

[image]

The notation is based on Petri Net graphics or icons, and the rules for "connecting" each icon (the squares and the circles) follows the rules for creating a Petri Net. The icon labelled T3 is something I "came up with" based on a high-level notation for representing more than one Petri Net element (I think by Nutt or Noe or both, Macro E-nets) -- I used the line properties found in PowerPoint.